# El Capitan, Finder.app, and Fan Performance

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, hardware, macos

Since upgrading today to El Capitan, my fan has been going non-stop. Under "Apps that Use Significant Energy", Finder.app is the culprit. Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Same here, apparently it may have to do with Path Finder + Finder combination, I'm reading on the PF forum... I'll check it out more in detail later.

Comment: Interesting. I am also using Path Finder. Have you upgraded Path Finder to the latest version? I am running an older version.

Comment: @Dave, I had Path Finder (v5) installed but haven't used it in ages. I followed the instructions [here](http://support.cocoatech.com/kb/installation-and-compatibility/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-path-finder) to uninstall it because my fans were going crazy too. After the uninstall, my fans haven't gone grazy, but keeping an eye on it.

Comment: I'll probably do that. I killed the Path Finder process and the fans are idle now.